# Android -> Pdf to byte array to bitmap

Tags: java, android

I'm programming an android app and finding some serious issues.
What I want to do is to generate a byte array from a pdf, and send this byte array to a different app so this one can generate a bitmap. Is that possible?

To create the byte array from the pdf I do this, and its look like its working:

```
            InputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = getAssets().open("TITULO.pdf");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            try {
                for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                    bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();`
```

And to generate the bitmap I'm doing this, and its returning a null value:

```
byte[] imageArray = callerIntent.getExtras().getByteArray(EXTRA_IMAGE);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length);
```

I would really appreciate any help here of some new ideas about how to this.

Comment: are you using some third party library to read the pdf?

Comment: How do you think you can you transform a pdf to a bitmap? I'm curious. The only way I can think of is taking a series of screenshots...

Comment: @ArtooDetoo, it is possible, but not in the direction is going through

Comment: @BlackBelt: That's interesting. I wasn't aware of this possibility.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo The code that passes from pdf to Byte array is taken from a website which said it was fully tested (http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-a-file-to-byte-array-then-convert-byte-array-to-a-file/), so I think its doing it okei. 
The point is that i dont think this array is useful to generate a bitmap :/ 
And no, im not using an third party library, just taking it from assets with the code i wrote

Comment: As I think you realised I'm a rookie in android programming, so dont take for granted some obvious stuff I should know, because probably i dont :P

Comment: That code might be tested, OK. What it does is: take a pdf, deconstruct it to bytes, and save it with another name (useful, uh?). But it doesn't change the contents of the file. A bitmap is something different from a pdf, with a different structure. I don't think you can write a bitmap out of the bytes of a pdf.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo I'm starting to be afraid that I cant write a bitmap from this array... I'm trying to transform this pdf to a bitmap, and later this bitmap to byte array (it may be stupid, but I need thi byte array hehe), any suggestion?

Comment: As I said, once you have your PDF displayed (in a WebView?), you might take a screenshot. Then you can convert this image to a byte array and do whatever you need to. This is how I would do that, but as BlackBelt says, you might be able to transform the pdf to an image (but I don't know how - you must investigate on this).